# Probability that $S$ is partitioned into 3 disjoint subsets with $n$ members in each subset

Tags: probability

A set contains $3n$ members.Let $P_n$ be the probability that $S$ is partitioned into 3 disjoint subsets with $n$ members in each subset such that the three largest numbers in $S$ are in different subsets.Then $\lim_{n\to \infty}P_n$.
$(A)\frac{2}{7}\hspace{1cm}(B)\frac{1}{7}\hspace{1cm}(C)\frac{1}{9}\hspace{1cm}(D)\frac{2}{9}$

---

I have a confusion in this problem.I dont know how to do set partitioning problems.Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: The problem as stated is ill defined : what's the probability distribution you put on the partitions? Obviously it's intended to be the uniform distribution (each partition has same probability), but it's fundamental to be clear about that

Comment: @Crostul: For $n=1$ it’s $1$.

Comment: @Tryss: It’s badly worded, but I think that the intention was to make it the uniform distribution **on partitions into three sets of size** $n$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : that's my interpretation too, but maths should not be about guessing what the other people have in mind ;)

Comment: @Tryss: Oh, I agree: the wording is abominable.

Answer (score 2):

I’m assuming that the problem (which is *very* poorly worded) was intended to be interpreted as follows:

> A set contains $3n$ members. Let $P_n$ be the probability that if $S$ is randomly partitioned into $3$ sets of size $n$, then the three largest members of $S$ are in different subsets. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}P_n=\;$?

Let the three largest members of $S$ be $a,b$, and $c$. When $S$ is partitioned into three parts, say $A_1,A_2$, and $A_3$ one of the parts must contain $a$; call it $A_1$. $P_n$ is the probability that $\{b,c\}$ is one of the pairs that can be obtained by taking one element from $A_2$ and the other from $A_3$.

- How many such pairs are there?

The pair $\{b,c\}$ could in principle be any pair from $S$ that doesn’t include $a$.

- How many such pairs are there?

Now $P_n$ is the ratio of those two numbers, which is a function of $n$. Take the limit of that ratio as $n\to\infty$, and you’ll have your answer.

Comment: Is the answer $\frac{2}{9}?$@Brian M.Scott

Comment: I have calculated probability as $\frac{6\times\frac{(3n-3)!}{(n-1)!(n-1)!(n-1)!}}{\frac{(3n)!}{(n)!(n)!(n)!}}$.And its limit at infinity is $\frac{2}{9}.$Am i correct?@Brian M.Scott

Comment: @learner_avid: The limit is correct, but the reasoning isn’t. Your numerator is the number of ways to partition all of the set except the three largest members into equal parts $A_1,A_2$, and $A_3$ and then to distribute the three largest members amongst those parts, one to each. Unfortunately, that doesn’t take into account the partitions of the whole set into three equal parts in which two or all three of the three largest members are in the same part. The approach that I suggested does take that into account.

Comment: What will be the final probability expression by your method@Brian M Scott

Comment: @learner_avid: The answer to the first question is $n^2$, and the answer to the second is $\binom{3n-1}2$, so the ratio is $$\frac{n^2}{\binom{3n-1}2} = \frac{2n^2}{(3n-1)(3n-2)} \underset{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow \frac29\;.$$